# Onchange event for combobox doesn't alert anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

This might sound a stupid question, but I'm trying to pix this past...I don't know how many hours.
I have a **jquery combobox** here.

Combobox code :-

```
<script>
  (function( $ ) {
    $.widget( "custom.combobox", {
      _create: function() {
        this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
          .insertAfter( this.element );

        this.element.hide();
        this._createAutocomplete();
        this._createShowAllButton();
      },

      _createAutocomplete: function() {
        var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
          value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

        this.input = $( "<input>" )
          .appendTo( this.wrapper )
          .val( value )
          .attr( "title", "" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
          .autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            minLength: 0,
            source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
          })
          .tooltip({
            tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
          });

        this._on( this.input, {
          autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.item.option.selected = true;
            this._trigger( "select", event, {
              item: ui.item.option
            });
          },

          autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
        });
      },

      _createShowAllButton: function() {
        var input = this.input,
          wasOpen = false;

        $( "<a>" )
          .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
          .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
          .tooltip()
          .appendTo( this.wrapper )
          .button({
            icons: {
              primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
            },
            text: false
          })
          .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
          .mousedown(function() {
            wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
          })
          .click(function() {
            input.focus();

            // Close if already visible
            if ( wasOpen ) {
              return;
            }

            // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
            input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
          });
      },

      _source: function( request, response ) {
        var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
        response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
          var text = $( this ).text();
          if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
            return {
              label: text,
              value: text,
              option: this
            };
        }) );
      },

      _removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {

        // Selected an item, nothing to do
        if ( ui.item ) {
          return;
        }

        // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
        var value = this.input.val(),
          valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
          valid = false;
        this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
          if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
            this.selected = valid = true;
            return false;
          }
        });

        // Found a match, nothing to do
        if ( valid ) {
          return;
        }

        // Remove invalid value
        this.input
          .val( "" )
          .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
          .tooltip( "open" );
        this.element.val( "" );
        this._delay(function() {
          this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
        }, 2500 );
        this.input.autocomplete( "instance" ).term = "";
      },

      _destroy: function() {
        this.wrapper.remove();
        this.element.show();
      }
    });
  })( jQuery );

  $(function() {
    $( "#combobox" ).combobox();
    $( "#toggle" ).click(function() {
      $( "#combobox" ).toggle();
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
        <select name="combobox" id="combobox" class="combobox">
          <option value=""></option>
             <?php
              try
              {
                $s = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM testing2");
              }
              catch(PDOException $e)
              {
                echo $e->getMessage();
              }
              while($test = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
              {
                ?>  
                <option value="<?php echo $test->indexid; ?>"><?php echo $test->v1; ?></option>
                <?php
              }
              ?>
        </select>
```

I'm trying to get the value of the select value from the selected box, but I'm unable to get it :-
Here's the code I've written for it :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#combobox').change(function(){
  var val = $("#combobox").val();
  alert(val);
})
</script>
```

But, this doesn't executes. What wrong am I doing here?

Here's the view-source of the combobox :-

```
<select name="combobox" id="combobox" class="combobox">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">value1</option>
  <option value="2">LoValue1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: try $(document).on('change', '#combobox', function(){

Comment: @BG101
No errors, here's a link for my page :- http://novostack.com/combo/t.php

Comment: I get "Not Acceptable!" when I follow that link.

Comment: @Barmar
Try and refresh it, you'd get to the page.

Comment: Tried repeatedly, still get the error.

Comment: **Not Acceptable!** An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security.

Comment: @Barmar
Here's a new link for you :- http://onu.im/t.php

Comment: The `<select>` is hidden, so how is the user supposed to change it and trigger the `.change()` handler?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90652/discussion-between-akshay-and-barmar).

Comment: @Barmar
What do you mean by hidden select?

Comment: The create method does `this.element.hide()`. So `#combo` is hidden, and the user can't change it. `.change()` isn't triggered when the value is changed in Javascript, only when it's changed by the user.

Comment: If you look at how jQuery UI works, each widget provides its own callback options, like `$("#foo").widget({ onChange: function() {} })`.

Comment: @Barmar
How would I go about adding something like this to my code?

Comment: Read a tutorial on writing jQuery plugins, they should show how to do option processing. Or you could have your code that processes input call `$(this.element).trigger("change")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have some issue around here. Line `125`:

```
this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
  if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
    $(this).prop("selected", true);
    valid = true;
    return false;
  }
});
```

I would generally go with a solution which is very well tested. So, I would request you to use [Select2](http://select2.github.io) for these kind of stuff. Have a look at the following snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#akshay").select2({
    "placeholder": "someplaceholder",
    "width": 200
  });
});

$("#akshay").change(function(){
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="akshay">
  <option value="item-1">Value</option>
  <option value="item-2">Item 2</option>
  <option value="item-3">Item 3</option>
  <option value="item-4">Item 4</option>
  <option value="item-5">Item 5</option>
  <option value="item-6">Item 6</option>
  <option value="item-7">Item 7</option>
  <option value="item-8">Item 8</option>
  <option value="item-9">Item 9</option>
  <option value="item-10">Item 10</option>
  <option value="item-11">Item 11</option>
  <option value="item-12">Item 12</option>
  <option value="item-13">Item 13</option>
  <option value="item-14">Item 14</option>
  <option value="item-15">Item 15</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:-

```
   this._on( this.input, {
      autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
        var alreadySelected = ui.item.option.selected;
        ui.item.option.selected = true;
        this._trigger( "select", event, {
          item: ui.item.option
        });
        if(!alreadySelected){
           $(this.element).change()
        }
      },
      autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
    });
```

jquery.ui sets the value but doesn't trigger the change event.

**EDIT**

Just added a flag to only trigger when the value selected if different to the previous value.

Comment: Can you perhaps provide an image link ?

Comment: image link? I put a break point after this._trigger and run $(this.element).change() when it hits on change of the dropdown. That shows the alert with the value. Nothing gets removed and I can do it continuously. did you see the edit?